# How should i add the values present in onActivityResult to the child views of ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandableListView consists of GroupViews & childViews. MyActivity is extending Activity. Now I want to add all the data present in for loop of onActivityResult to childViews of ExpandableListView. How should I do this..?

Please help me...

Anyone can plz help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you have your Adapter class for your ExpandableListVieW. Your Adapter class is inicialized by some form of data you are storing. Update that storage with the new data. I read in a lot of posts to call the notifyDataSetChanged() method on your adapter, it depends on what kind of Adapter you are using. Mine Adapter extends from BaseAdapter, that class does not have that function, but it updates my list automaticly after i added the new data to my storage.